# remove points from excel file line chart using python package xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, linechart, points, xlsxwriter

I have this chart, created using python package `xlsxwriter` and I wanna remove all the points in the middle and only keep the first one and last one.
before :
[image: enter ima ge description here] Final results wanted.:

[image]

I tried the attribute `points` but unfortunate, it didn't work for me.

```
line_chart.add_series(
                        {
                            'values': '='+worksheet_name+'!$C$'+str(row_range+1)+':$I'+str(row_range+1),
                            'marker': {'type': 'diamond'},
                            'data_labels': {'value': True, 'category': True, 'position': 'center', 'leader_lines': True},
                            
                            'points': [
                                    {'fill': {'color': 'green'}},
                                    None,
                                    None,
                                    None,
                                    None,
                                    None,
                                    {'fill': {'color': 'red'}}
                                ],
                            'trendline': {
                                        'type': 'polynomial',
                                        'name': 'My trend name',
                                        'order': 2,
                                        'forward': 0.5,
                                        'backward': 0.5,
                                        'line': {
                                                'color': 'red',
                                                'width': 1,
                                                'dash_type': 'long_dash'
                                               }
                                        }

                        }
                    )
```

I also tried:

```
line_chart.set_x_axis({
                'major_gridlines': {'visible': False},
                'minor_gridlines': {'visible': False}
                'delete_series': [1, 6]
                })
```

no luck.
Anobody can help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be clear, what you wish to do is to remove data labels, not points. However, that isn't possible with XlsxWriter.

Comment: I thought the same, because I spent couple days reading the documentation online with no lead.Thank you @jmcnamara!